# How to split a column in many different columns?

Tags: pandas, split, strsplit

I have a dataset and in one of it columns I have many values that I want to convert to new columns:

```
"{'availabilities': {'bikes': 4, 'stands': 28, 'mechanicalBikes': 4, 'electricalBikes': 0, 'electricalInternalBatteryBikes': 0, 'electricalRemovableBatteryBikes': 0}, 'capacity': 32}"
```

I tried to use str.split() and received the error because of the patterns.

```
bikes_table_ready[['availabilities',
                   'bikes',
                   'stands',
                   'mechanicalBikes',
                   'electricalBikes',
                   'electricalInternalBatteryBikes',
                   'electricalRemovableBatteryBikes',
                   'capacity']]= bikes_table_ready.totalStands.str.extract('{.}', expand=True)

ValueError: pattern contains no capture groups
```

Which patterns should I use to have it done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) with [`pandas.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html).

With a dataframe `df` with two columns (`id`) and the column to be splitted (`col`), it gives this :

```
import ast
​
df["col"] = df["col"].apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x.strip('"')))
​
out = df.join(pd.json_normalize(df.pop("col").str["availabilities"]))
```

##### # Output :

```
print(out.to_string())
      id  bikes  stands  mechanicalBikes  electricalBikes  electricalInternalBatteryBikes  electricalRemovableBatteryBikes
0  id001      4      28                4                0                               0                                0
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the data you are trying to use the method str.split() is not actually a string. Check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_datatypes.asp) to find more about data types. It seems you are trying to retrieve the information from a Python List "[xxx] Or Dictionary "dicName{"Key":"value}". If that's the case, try checking [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp) which talks about how to use Python Lists or [this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp) which talks about dictionaries.